# Need to get HTML header to stay static when page is resized

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my header to stay put whenever I resize my page, but it will continue to move upward every time I increase the width of the page. My code is below...

```css
.header-container {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
  width: 70%;
}

.header-container-1 {
  margin-top: -35rem;
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://www.champneys.com/getattachment/0b7088bf-e999-4304-91e6-77e6330760bc/champneys-facials.jpg?lang=en-gb&ext=.jpg" alt="Image cannot be displayed">
<div class="header-container-1">
  <div class="header-container">
    <h3 class="first-h3">
      Look & Feel Better
    </h3>
    <h1 class="business-name">
      PASSIONATE HEALING
    </h1>
    <h2 class="first-h2">
      Out With the Old
      <br> In With the New
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "header"? The image or the text or both? As it is, the text doesn't move up or down when you resize the page so it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: My apologies, by "header" I am referring to the text for h1, h2, and h3. When I increase the size of my page, the header begins to move upward every time and I am not sure why. I just want it to remain where it is at over the image so that when I resize the page I don't have to worry about the text going off of the page.

Comment: I ran your code and didn't find any issue with "headers moving upwards". Can you add before and after resizing pics to your question?

Comment: Do you mean horizontally? Because that's the only shifting I see

Comment: If you want the text to stay over the same part of the image regardless of viewport dimensions you’ll have to position it in relation to the image, rem have nothing to do with that. But is the text staying over the same part of the image what you require?

Comment: @AHaworth Yes! Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

For explanation purposes:

I've cleaned up your HTML and condensed it to a single container using a flexbox layout. I've set up the image as a background image so we don't have to worry about positioning it with the text and made it so that it automatically sizes when the window adjusts. I've set the width and height attributes so we can align our content with flexbox properties and then added some padding to move the text around but with `align-items: left` the text should stay in place when you scale the window.

By doing this, we've avoided any potential issues with negative margins, simplified the structure of your code, and prevented the text from shifting.

Hopefully, that takes care of it for you

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 3rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30rem;
  background-image: url('https://www.champneys.com/getattachment/0b7088bf-e999-4304-91e6-77e6330760bc/champneys-facials.jpg?lang=en-gb&ext=.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.first-h3 {
  padding: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
}

.business-name {
  padding: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container">
  <h3 class="first-h3">
    Look &#38; Feel Better
  </h3>
  <h1 class="business-name">
    PASSIONATE HEALING
  </h1>
  <h2 class="first-h2">
    Out With the Old
  </h2>
  <h2 class="first-h2">
    In With the New
  </h2>
</div>
```